# How to refer the cell after a merged column in a row?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to merge some cells in a row. But I am not able to refer the next available cell after the merged cells in the same row.

```
Server 1
         Socket 1  VM1  10
                   VM2  4
         Socket 2  VM1  5
                   VM2  6
```

So I need to merge 10 cells in 1 row for Socket 1 VM1. After this I want to merge 4 cells for VM2. Then 5 cells for Socket 2 VM1 and then 6 cells for VM2.

My code is failing after first iteration only. That is, I am able to merge only first 10 cells. I am not able to merge cells in the same row for VM2 in and further .

```
last = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VIM 1").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

j = 1       'column index
lcol = 2    'last filled column

For i = 2 To last

    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VIM 1").Cells(i, j).Text, “Server”, 1) Then

        If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VIM 1").Cells(i + 1, 2).Text, “Socket1”, 1) Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VIM 1").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = "" Then

            count = count + 1


            For l = 1 To count


                 pcpu = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VIM 1").Cells(i + 1, 4).Value / 2

                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VNF Placement").Range(Cells(11, lcol), Cells(11, pcpu + 1)).Merge

                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VNF Placement").Cells(11, lcol).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VIM 1").Cells(i + 1, 3).Value

                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VNF Placement").Cells(11, lcol).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 + i

                 lcol = Cells(11, Columns.count).MergeArea.Columns.count + 1


            Next l
        End If

      End If
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example `x` will hold the number of columns in your merged range so you only need to add `x + 1` to get your desired column:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Long

    x = Range("A1").MergeArea.Columns.Count 'columns
    x = Range("A1").MergeArea.Rows.Count 'Also for rows

End Sub
```

Comment: @Ninja of course it didn't help my code was just an example to lead you. Use the logic to change yours.